# a problem from Artin, need a hint

Tags: abstract-algebra

part(b):  I can prove the kernel is $(y^2-xy-x^3)$ and identify the image, but what kind of  intuition should I get from the variety or to explain what?  Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometric intuition here is that (a) describes a curve with a cusp at the origin - see the picture at the top of [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)), which happens to use precisely the same curve to illustrate what a cusp is - whereas (b) describes a deformation of that curve so that the cusp is removed and replaced with a simple self-intersection at the origin.

Let's think of $t$ as time, and imagine a particle whose position at time $t$ is $(t^2-t,t^3-t)$. The particle starts at the origin when $t=0$, takes a detour in the all-negative quadrant between $t=0$ and $t=1$, before returning to the origin at $t=1$ (and flying off to infinity along the positive quadrant at all other times).

[image: parametric plot]

We can interpolate between cases (a) and (b) by modifying the motion of the particle such that its position at time $t$ is $(t^2-\epsilon t, t^3-\epsilon^2 t)$. When $0<\epsilon<1$, this particle returns to the origin at time $t=\epsilon$, and if you perform a similar computation as in case (b) you will find that the image is the set of polynomials $p(t)$ satisfying $p(0)=p(\epsilon)$. Finally, taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ we see that this condition becomes $p'(0)=0$, or in physical terms the particle has speed $0$ at the origin - it takes an "infinitesimal rest" while changing its direction.